# Android Same Position Textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an energy watch app with android. I am getting data with mysql.

I want to show the data over a house floor plan, like this one:

[image: Plan]

I changed textview text to my data. Example I am showing a room with 10 kW. 
My problem is I made position with relative layout. When screen change. Bigger or smaller. My textview positions are changing. Its looking very bad.

How can I do same position over an image.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot and how you want to change it?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to find the relative position of your `textViews` inside your plan. Settings something like `margin_left=80dp` won't be responsive.

## The good news!

It's now possible with **support library version 23** to set a percentage padding/margin by using `android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout` or `android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout`.

You'll have to figure out the percent position of your views inside the plan and you're good to go.

### Some code

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background:"@drawables/your_plan">

     <EditText
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:layout_widthPercent="13%"
         app:layout_marginStartPercent="13%"
         app:layout_marginEndPercent="13%"
         android:text="Because 13 is my lucky number"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

### Documentation

- [PercentFrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html)
- [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)
- [PercentLayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutParams.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I do with lower than 23. My devices are kitkat and jelly bean.

Comment: It'll work fine with API levels lower than 23, as I said use the support lib.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do it. I worked 3 day for it. today I do it in 1 hour. Very thanks.

Comment: Hello again. @AnixPasBesoin I did it in emulator. There are no problem. I tried it in my real device. Looking this. http://imgur.com/RSoWhP4

Comment: @SelimErkan I'm sure you didn't set your attributes as the docs specifies it. If you set an `app:layout_widthPercent` don't set an `app:layout_heightPercent` and vice versa. Check the docs or this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38379118/3503855).

Comment: My Example edittext code <EditText
            android:editable="false"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_marginStartPercent="34%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="46%"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/i_bewling5"
            android:text="..."/>

Comment: @SelimErkan If you didn't solve this yet, you can update your question.